# Capturing DNS responses with PCap.Net?

Tags: .net, dns, winpcap, sharppcap, pcap.net

Q1 - Is it possible to capture DNS request/responses with the library?

Q2 - If yes, once I have the packet does anyone have any sample code
that shows how I could extract the fields from the DNS response?  In
particular the IP address that DNS resolved for the given DNS name
provided in particular.

Comment: See the discussion in http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=223803

Comment: A DNS parser is in development for SharpPcap. Parsing the questions/answers dynamically for all use cases can get pretty hairy but it's on the todo list for the near future.

Comment: Evan - sorry for the revival of an ancient thread, but was the DNS parser for SharpPcap ever completed?  I'm looking to parse DNS request and response packets using SharpPcap / Packet.Net but haven't found this in the latest downloads (or on the web).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Sample code would be a bit on the long side, though...

In essence, you need to:

1. extract the ethernet header
2. extract the IP header
3. extract the UDP header [assuming the packet isn't fragmented, or using TCP]
4. extract the DNS payload

then handle the rest of the packet according to the very thorough description given in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034).

In practise that means:

1. ignore requests - all the info you need is in responses (`QR == 1`)
2. check for `RCODE == 0` and `ANCOUNT > 0`
3. look in the *Question* section to find the name that was queried
4. look for answers in the *Answer* (duh!) section

To further complicate matters you have to handle DNS labels (series of *`<count><data...>`* fields) and potentially handle compressed labels too!

This sounds nasty, but none of it is actually *that* hard.  I have C++ code that does all this and it's not that long, but I can't release it.

Comment: excellent - thanks Alnitak, I'll give this a go today if I can

Comment: Alnitak - I'm managing to pick up the UDP packets, however I'm not too sure how to break it down from the PcapDotNet.Packets.Transport.UdpDatagram object level further? Here's a snapshot I what I can see in VS2010 postimage.org/image.php?v=aV7un3J . Am I suppose to parse manually the "((packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Udp).Payload).Buffer" value for example?

Comment: @Greg - yes, that `Buffer` variable should contain step 4 of what I described above - the DNS payload.